# crtp and type visibility

Tags: c++, templates, crtp

I have this puzzle which I am trying to solve, and fundamentally it boils down to the following example:

```
template <typename CT>
struct A
{
  typedef typename CT::VALUE_T FOO; // FOO is dependent on CT
};

template <typename CT>
struct B
{
  typedef typename CT::BAR BAR;

  BAR foo() {}
};

template <typename DT>
struct C : B<C<DT> >
{
  typedef DT VALUE_T;

  typedef typename A<C>::FOO BAR;
};

int main () {
  C<int> c;
}
```

I can try to explain the above (I've tried about three times and deleted the text!), but basically the requirements are:

1. `C` must inherit from `B` typed with `C` (exploiting CRTP), i.e. `B<C<>>`
2. `C` is the only one that can instantiate `A` (i.e. `A` has to be typed with `C`)
3. `A` is the only one that can define `FOO` (`FOO` is dependent on the type `CT`, the relationship is more complicated than that presented)

The problem (as you can see with the above code) is that the `BAR` type is available only within `C` and this is incomplete when `B` is instantiated, hence `B` does not see the `BAR` type of the template argument `CT` (`C<int>`). Unfortunately within `B`, the type `BAR` is used as arguments to functions, and return types (i.e. not just limited to function scope - as a result I cannot simply move the typedef to function scope).

Is there a way around this? I cannot break the above stated relationships (unless as a last resort). Presumably with c++11, I could use `auto` and get around the need to have the `BAR` typedef in `B`, however this is currently not yet an option.

EDIT: following on from @bitmasks' comment, some more information.

1. The code in `A` and `B` is used in quite a few binaries in different situations, the only unique situation in this case is that `C` derives from `B`, in the other instances, `C` owns an instance of something derived from `B`.
2. The template arguments can be changed (in `A` and `B`), as long as they can be defaulted to values which doesn't require changing existing uses of `A` and `B`. The same set of types must be available either as template parameter that is defaulted or some other mechanism.

I'm using templates here simply because I require the tight-coupling and I needed the flexibility to use the code in different situations.

Descriptions of components:

- `A` is best described as a container, and `FOO` really is an iterator, what it contains is defined by a typedef of the template parameter
- `B` is best described as a base class which contains a set of functions which are called by some components *owned* by an instance of `C`. In the previous cases, those components were passed a reference to things derived from `B` (and those *things* are also owned by `C`), in this instance, I'm providing a reference to `C` itself.

The main complication arises from accessing the container `A`, previously the relationship between `B` and `C` is that `C` *has an instance* of `B`, but now `C` *is an instance* of `B` - this change in semantics breaks the way types are injected into the classes.

Comment: I've been thinking about your quandary for quite a while now, and I think you have to provide more information why you are doing the detour via all these aliases and what changes to your example are admissible (e.g. extra parameters, additional types, etc.).

Comment: @bitmask, thanks for your time, I've added more information, short of the real code (which I cannot post as it's highly sensitive), I'm trying to describe the situation in the update. The crux of the problem is that the types must be available whether the relationship between `C` and `B` is either *has a* or *is a*.

Comment: @Nim: Very confusing and nicely answered by bitmask. Can you tell why you are in such a situation ?

Comment: @ArunMu, as I explained, I am trying to use a piece of code that was designed for a *has a* relationship in an *is a* relationship. In it's designed form, the typedefs are available nicely, when changing to inheritance, the derived class which defines the types are incomplete in the context of the base class. Interesting, I thought my simple example conveyed the problem. And agree, bitmask's solution is correct, now I need to see how I can translate to what I am doing (this the problem with trying to oversimplify a real world problem.. :) )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can combat the cyclic `typedef` requirement with default template parameters. The following works as intended (as far as I understand your question) and leaves you (almost) all the liberties of your original code:

```
template <typename CT, typename CTVALUE_T = typename CT::VALUE_T>
struct A
{
    //typedef typename CT::VALUE_T FOO; // FOO is dependent on CT
    typedef CTVALUE_T FOO; // FOO is dependent on CT
};

template <typename CT, typename CTBAR = typename CT::BAR>
struct B
{
    //typedef typename CT::BAR BAR;
    typedef CTBAR BAR;

    BAR foo() {return 0;}
};

template <typename DT> struct VALUE_T__from__DT {
  typedef DT VALUE_T;
};

template <typename DT, template <class T> class _C_ > struct BAR__from__DT {
  typedef typename A<_C_<DT> , typename VALUE_T__from__DT<DT>::VALUE_T >::FOO BAR;
};

template <typename DT>
struct C : B<C<DT>, typename BAR__from__DT<DT, C >::BAR >
{
    //typedef DT VALUE_T;

    //typedef typename A<C>::FOO BAR;
};

int main () {
    C<int> c;
    int x = c.foo();
    (void)x;
    return 0;
}
```

The names of the helper template types are horrible, perhaps you can find better names.

The core trick is that the definition of the problematic `typedef`s is put in a separate meta-container (i.e. a container for traits) such that you can still do any voodoo there.

I commented the unnecessary typedefs out (but left them there so you have a better chance to figure out what I'm doing there).

Does that fit your need?

Comment: @ArunMu: Thanks. It's just that I'm utterly incapable to resist an interesting (apparently trivial, yet with no apparent solutions) puzzle.

Comment: +1, indeed - this looks good, I need to see how I can translate this to my real code now. I just need to ensure that `BAR__from__DT::BAR` is the same as `A<C>::FOO BAR`..

Comment: @Nim: Trivial; Typedef the latter as the former. :)

Comment: @bitmask, yip.. :) thanks.. will revert once it's in place.. Due to the time it was taking, I changed my approach back to a *has a* relationship - had to write a whole bunch of other code as a result - ah well.